# .ics attachment in gmail.com not saved

Tags: firefox, gmail, google-calendar

My problem is that `.ics` attachments from E-Mails, which I open in GMail.com, are not saved in Google Calendar, although I press "Safe". More specifically, the appointment is saved but disappears on reload.

The attached picture shows that everything looks normal when I use GMail's dialogue to import an `.ics` into the calendar (Notice the orange bar on top, which - in German - states that the `.ics` has successfully been imported):

[image: Everything looks normal]

However, when I reload the calendar, it looks like

[image: No appointment saved]

I'm using FF 36.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, but I failed on a Windows 7 Machine as well. Cookies are allowed (if that matters). I also tried to change the calendar entry somehow (i.e. another time or date), but without positive effect.

Comment: I also approached the google productforum on https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!mydiscussions/calendar/0QDAbumw5-k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this problem from time to time. There are a few things I know of to combat this issue. First, be sure there is no date conflicts that you're not noticing. I've never seen that [image] icon on my calender and it could be a sign of a conflicting date

1. Be sure you're using the direct import method. There are alternate ways to import .ics files be sure you're using this button
   [image: this button]
2. When you are in the calender with the event (in your case) temporarily in the calender pull it around a bit to make sure it gets updated with the servers and you will see the verification at the top of the page
3. If all else fails you can manually add a calender event via .ics after you download the .ics file which has had 100% successes rate for me    [image]

Comment: Last solution worked, but not the second (at least not on first try). What do you mean by the http://i.stack.imgur.com/KCAcg.png image? Never seen that.

Comment: It's in the top corner of your imported event

Comment: Can't find it. Is it above the email or already in the calendar view?